# How to make XSL transforms in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, xslt

The XsltProcessor class from the dart:html library is deprecated.

What library should I use to make XSL transforms in Flutter/Dart?

I would like to transform an xml file with an xsl file into an html / pdf file

Comment: Have you looked at SaxonJS?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay,
I don't know how to integrate a javascript package into a Flutter project. If you have any advice on how to do this, I would like to hear from you.

Comment: Well, even if deprecated, if you want to do XML to HTML transformation with XSLT and the platform supports the XsltProcessor from the browser, you can use it, I would think.

Comment: I don't know Flutter, so I can't help with the integration, but Dart seems to be able to call JS APIs so I assume it's possible. Does https://dev.to/graphicbeacon/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-your-dart-applications--4mc6 help?